# Nextcloud sync without sharing git

Tags: sync, nextcloud

I have a directory on my laptop that I wish to sync to a shared Nextcloud folder. (I am using Linux, and the latest version of Nextcloud). I do *not* wish to sync the `.git` folder inside my repository as the Nextcloud directory is shared with other people, but I am not sure how to do avoid syncing this. I tried removing the sync connection for `.git`, but this meant that it got deleted locally from my laptop, and I want to keep my version of the .git directory locally. I removed the sync connection for the main synced director, and created a file `sync-exclude.lst` with the following lines

```
.git/*
.git
.git/
```

and re-enabled the sync. On restoring my (local) `.git` folder from backup, it immediately started syncing remotely.

There is again the option to "remove folder sync connection" in the GUI, but if I uncheck the box next to ".git" then it warns that the folder will be deleted locally.

How can I create a synced folder and tell NextCloud to completely ignore, never sync, and never delete, a certain subfolder?

Comment: https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/issues/4889#issue-1361087152

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it sounds like you've grabbed the wrong end of the stick on the sync-exclude.lst file...

The right way to do it, according to the documentation is to use the ignored files editor https://docs.nextcloud.com/desktop/latest/navigating.html#using-the-ignored-files-editor

The sync-exclude.lst file is a system-wide ignore list not just a file you create in a folder you are syncing. The documentation explicitly says not to edit this file.

Comment: It should be possible to add sync-exclude.lst files on any level of the synced directory tree, similar to .gitignore. I've also used the GUI ignored files editor to ignore .git/ but it doesn't work.